# Oracle Query on Regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm trying to use Regexp_substr to extract the unit no from the Property Field.
Below is the query.

```
regexp_substr(PROPERTY,'(#)[^\S]+ ')
```

While some of the results are correct, but others came back like below:

```
#05-08 DOVER PARKVIEW
```

May I know what do I need to do to omit all the alphabets or wordings?
Thank you.

Comment: So what is the input string and what is the result you need? BTW, is it Oracle 11g/12g or older?

Comment: And what did you plan to match with `[^\S]`?

Comment: I'm trying to match the unit number only, which is #05-08. But this is just one format, there are other unit numbers which looks like #19-1215 or #06-143

Comment: Ok, try `regexp_substr(s, '#(\d+-\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Thanks! It works like wonder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\S]` pattern matches any char but a `\` and a capital letter `S`.

You need to capture 1+ digits followed with `-` and again 1+ digits after a `#` and extract that part of the match only with

```
regexp_substr(PROPERTY, '#(\d+-\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

The last `1` argument tells the regex engine to extract the contents of the capturing group with ID 1 (it is the only capturing group in the pattern anyway).

- `#` - a literal `#`
- `(\d+-\d+)` - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/SSEDA13076):

```
select regexp_substr('#05-08 DOVER PARKVIEW', '#(\d+-\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as RESULT from dual
```

[image]